# Null Pointer Error when calling function by interface

Tags: java, android, interface

I have an interface defined as

```
public interface UpdateList {
    public void updateList();
}
```

That is implemented as

```
@Override
public void updateList() {
    arrAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

when I call the function from inside the function that I have defined it in it will run normally, however when I call it by the interface I get a NullPointer exception on `arrAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here is how I call it by the interface, from a Activity that has multiple Fragments, that implement the `UpdateList` interface, in a ViwePager

```
for (int i=0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    ((UpdateList) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i)).updateList();
}
```

where `mSectionsPagerAdapter` is an implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Edit:** since people are assuming that it is null, arrAdapter is instantiated when the Fragment is created.

**Edit 2:** my apologies to those who were saying that it is null, I was in idiot and have now realised where the error is. `mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i)` returns a new instance of the Fragment for that position, but nothing get instatiated in it until its onCreateView is called, which does not happen since that fragment is never displayed.

So my question should probably have been how do I get the Fragment instances that the Viewpager has created?

Comment: have you checked that arrAdapter is not null?

Comment: most likely `arrAdapter` is `null`. you can't *do any operation* on *nothing*

Comment: @panini it shouldn't be null since it gets set when the Fragment is created, and the fragment is currently on screen when this is being called. the function is also called about 3 times before I get the error by the fragment that it is a part of

Comment: @Spurdow mSectionsPagerAdapter shouldn't be an instance of updateList, the result from mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i) should be.

Comment: Even though you already know the cause, could you post the LogCat? Oh, and I think you should check if the `Fragment` is null or not before you call `updateList()`. There is a possibility that unseen fragments will be null, though I can't really confirm it.

Comment: will you try `((Fragment-that-implemented-UpdateList) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i)).updateList();` not the `UpdateList` , cause if your fragment really did implemented it, it should have that implementation.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox yo were correct, since I was accidentally creating a new fragment instead of using one that already existed...